# I am trying to generate two values from probability distributions, but one distribution is not generating values correctly

Tags: matlab, if-statement, probability, distribution

I am generating a random value from a beta probability distribution. Based on where that value sits in terms of standard deviations I want to select a random value from a lognormal distribution that also sits in that same standard deviation range.

The beta distribution value generates no problem, but the lognormal value only generates a value rarely (maybe once or twice in the 300 iterations). Not exactly sure why this is happening, which is likely a result of my very rudimentary understanding of MATLAB and coding in general. Help would be much appreciated!

Basically I've created a series of if and and statements that check where the random beta distribution value sits, and if it is within a certain standard deviation range then the code checks if the random lognormal value is in within that same range. If they are within the same range the code ends, if not the code repeats. But I am getting 0 for most if not all the lognormal values in my final array.

```
close all;
clc;


d= xlsread('Poro perm data for Clarke Lake.xlsx');                                                                               
pdPor = d(:,2);
pdPerm = d(:,5);

meanPor = mean(pdPor);
stdPor = std(pdPor);

meanPerm = mean(pdPerm);
stdPerm = std(pdPerm);

porosity_permeability = zeros(300,2); % openspace for array
temp=[];
%Perm = [1:300,1];
Perm = zeros(1,300);
for i=1:300
    porRandom = betarnd(3.1800,44.87,[1 1]);
    por(i) = porRandom;

    mu=1.0130;
    sigma = 2.574;
    permRandom =lognrnd(mu,sigma);

    if porRandom <=( meanPor + stdPor) && porRandom >= (meanPor - stdPor)                           

        if permRandom <= (meanPerm + stdPerm) && permRandom >= (meanPerm - stdPerm) 
            Perm(i) = permRandom; 
        end
    elseif porRandom < (meanPor - stdPor) && porRandom > (meanPor - stdPor*2)                 

           if permRandom < (meanPerm - stdPerm) && permRandom > (meanPerm - stdPerm*2) 

              Perm(i) = permRandom; 
           end
    elseif porRandom < (meanPor - stdPor*2)                                              


           if permRandom < (meanPerm - stdPerm*2)  
              Perm(i) = permRandom;
           end
    elseif porRandom > (meanPor + stdPor) && porRandom < (meanPor + stdpdPor*2)         

            if permRandom > (meanPerm + stdPerm) && permRandom < (meanPerm + stdPerm*2)
                Perm(i) = permRandom;
            end
    else porRandom > (meanPor + stdPor*2)                                        

            if permRandom > (meanPerm + stdPerm*2)   
                Perm(i) = permRandom;
            end
    end


end

% CONCATENATED ARRAYS
porosity_permeability=cat(1,por,Perm);
```

As described before, I want my final result to be a 2x300 matrix with the beta values in the first row and the lognormal values in the second row. The beta values generate perfectly fine, but the lognormal values are, for the most part, 0, with only a few runs producing the correct values.

Comment: Your last `else` is wrong. Either it should be an `elseif` which takes a condition, or there should not be any condition, since `else` is the "if every previous condition was false, do this" fail-safe. You should see `ans logical 1` or `ans = logical 0` being printed to your command window whenever this clause is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found your problem. You initialize the `Perm` vector to all zeros and according to your logic block within the loop you fail to update 'Perm' at index i if the inner `if` statement is false. Since you are in a for loop you continue on to the next iteration e.g i = i+1 and therefore `Perm` at the last index can never be updated. Instead use a while loop and set your iterator to advance by one only when your inner `if` statement is true. Now you are guaranteed to continue looping until you've finished updating all indices of the 'Perm' vector. Her is the updated loop

```
i =1;
while i<=300
    porRandom = betarnd(3.1800,44.87,[1 1]);
    por(i) = porRandom;

    mu=1.0130;
    sigma = 2.574;
    permRandom =lognrnd(mu,sigma);

    if porRandom <=( meanPor + stdPor) && porRandom >= (meanPor - stdPor)                           

        if permRandom <= (meanPerm + stdPerm) && permRandom >= (meanPerm - stdPerm) 
            Perm(i) = permRandom;
            i= i+1;
        end
    elseif porRandom < (meanPor - stdPor) && porRandom > (meanPor - stdPor*2)                 

           if permRandom < (meanPerm - stdPerm) && permRandom > (meanPerm - stdPerm*2) 
              Perm(i) = permRandom;
              i= i+1;
           end
    elseif porRandom < (meanPor - stdPor*2)                                              


           if permRandom < (meanPerm - stdPerm*2)  
              Perm(i) = permRandom;
              i= i+1;
           end
    elseif porRandom > (meanPor + stdPor) && porRandom < (meanPor + stdpdPor*2)         

            if permRandom > (meanPerm + stdPerm) && permRandom < (meanPerm + stdPerm*2)
                Perm(i) = permRandom;
                i= i+1;
            end
    elseif porRandom > (meanPor + stdPor*2)                                        

            if permRandom > (meanPerm + stdPerm*2)   
                Perm(i) = permRandom;
                i= i+1;
            end
    end


end
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you very much. The lognormal values seem to be generating correctly. However, there still seems to be an issue. Each porRandom that is generated is between 0.2 - 0.28, which are values that are likely +2 standard deviations above the mean. The value range should be more like 0.01 - 0.28 (the mean is 0.07). Is this a result of only the last elseif statement (elseif porRandom > (meanPor + stdPor*2)) being selected? I apologize if my terminology is off, I am still learning things. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not following your question. The value for `porRandom` is being drawn from a beta distribution with parameters you've specified the output of sampling the beta distribution produces a range from 0 to 0.2. What is the mean you are speaking about?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. The beta distribution includes a range of values from 0.01 to 0.28, however, the output for porRandom in the array only includes values ~ 0.2 - 0.28. I should expect values from 0.01 to 0.28 within the final array, and not only high values between 0.2 - 0.28. Does that make sense? (Again, I apologize if I am not making sense).